# Jquery Jtable load Json from ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jquery-jtable

I am using `jtable.org-s` library for showing rows in a table. For populating rows I used `listAction` like this:

```
actions: {
  listAction: '/Passengers/Search'
},
```

This URL returned valid json and everything worked fine. But I want to call the URL manually from ajax, because this URL returns more info than rows. It also returns info I need for other form elements, such as search result items count, woman/man ratio and etc.

So, I want to ajax call, and load the response to my `jtable`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Passengers/Search',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    // here I would like to inject the Json(data) to my table
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FunctionsAsActions](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/FunctionsAsActions) feature of [jquery-jtable](http://www.jtable.org).
 In ajax success filter you can filter your response data and by using `$dfd.resolve(data);` you can load filtered data to jquery-jtable.
For example:

```
listAction: function (postData, jtParams) {
                    console.log("Loading from custom function...");
                    return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Demo/StudentList?jtStartIndex=' + jtParams.jtStartIndex + '&jtPageSize=' + jtParams.jtPageSize + '&jtSorting=' + jtParams.jtSorting,
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: postData,
                            success: function (data) {
                                //filter your data here and then pass filtered data to $dfd.resolve function

                                $dfd.resolve(data);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                $dfd.reject();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggested by abpatil is a good answer.

A simpler solution may be to use the jTable `recordsLoaded` event http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Events#event-recordsLoaded

The handler is given an event data object which has two components. `data.records` which is an array of all the records sent by the server, and `data.serverResponse` which is the full json response from the server.

You can loop through the records and process any extra fields.

The server can also send extra json properties not used by jTable and you can process the `data.serverResponse` here and use them in other page elements.